# Item in RecyclerView occupies space but accidentally became invisible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this RecyclerView to display a trend flow. But as you can see, the item between these two became invisible accidentally but still occupies the exact height and width as it should be according to its data amount.

[image][image]

I'm sure that I don't have any code to set the whole ViewHolder invisible in my adapter. Since my data comes back in json string format, will this happen when json data's format isn't completely standard? But I don't see any error output when decoding the json string. 
Besides, I see this error log when refreshing RecyclerView:

```
E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout
```

What's the cause of this error? I've seen it when refreshing other RecyclerViews even more, but nothing like this has happened. 
I initialize the RecyclerView in `TrendFragment.java`

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.trend_list);
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyApplication.getContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
adapter = new GeneralTrendAdapter(context, (RootActivity) getActivity(), list, trend_type);
adapter.setLikeClickInterface(this);
adapter.setCommentClickInterface(this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's some key code in `GeneralTrendAdapter.onBindViewHolder()`

```
            if (trendType == FlagManager.TREND_FRIEND) {
                viewHolder.group_header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.like_num_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.comment_num_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//    Set like users view
                if (post.isParticipated() && post.getLikeUsers().size() > 0) {
                    viewHolder.like_user_root.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String firstUsername = post.getLikeUsers().get(0).getUsername();
                    String displayName = firstUsername;
                    String displayText;

                    if (post.getLikeUsers().size() == 1) {
                        if (firstUsername.length() > 10) {
                            displayName = firstUsername.substring(0, 11) + "..";
                        }
                        displayText = displayName + "点赞了";
                    } else {
                        if (firstUsername.length() > 7) {
                            displayName = firstUsername.substring(0, 8) + "..";
                        }
                        displayText = displayName + "等" + post.getLikeUsers().size() + "位好友点赞了";
                    }
                    viewHolder.like_user_text.setText(displayText);

                } else {
                    viewHolder.like_user_root.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

//    Set reply view
                if (post.getReply() != null && post.getReply().size() > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + post.getContent() + " comment list size > 0");
                    viewHolder.interaction_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.comment_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyApplication.getContext()));
                    InnerCommentAdapter adapter = new InnerCommentAdapter(activity, context, post.getReply(),
                            commentClickInterface);
                    viewHolder.comment_list.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    viewHolder.interaction_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            } else {
                viewHolder.group_header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: Did you set any layout manager to your RecyclerView object?

Comment: @KirylTkach I guess I did. Otherwise other items won't be visible either, right?

Comment: Can you provide some code where you create RecyclerView object and set data?

Comment: @KirylTkach Yes, I've updated my question.

Comment: use wrap content on your single item layout

Comment: @PembaTamang I did use wrap content and the height of the item layout was not manually set at all.. It’s like all data was analyzed and displayed but item layout became invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the layout used for showing recycler item data has **height** set to `match_parent`. You should set the height to `wrap_content`.

If that is not the case, then post your whole adapter class along with item layout XML too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turned out that the cause is the ShadowView I used in item's layout, which is unstable when item's height value is big.